# How to properly export string columns in csv?

Tags: export, csv-format

How can I make sure that certain string columns of a matrix I want to export get properly formatted? That is, all quotes escaped, and every string wrapped in quotes. Here's what happens now:

[image]

According to the [csv specs](http://edoceo.com/utilitas/csv-file-format), embedded double-quote characters must be doubled, and the field must be delimited with double-quotes.

I know about the "TextDelimiter" option, but the proper escaping eludes me.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the string as you require by using a replacement.

```
Export["text.csv",
 {{1, "2", 3}, {1, "2", 3}} /.
  a_String :> StringJoin["\"", a, "\""]]

FilePrint["text.csv"]
```

> ```
> 1, "2", 3
> 1, "2", 3
> ```

**Edit further to comments**

Internal quotes can be put into the CSV according to the OP's linked spec.

```
Export["text.csv",
 {{1, "2 \"\"two\"\" 2", 3}, {1, "2 \"\"two\"\" 2", 3}} /.
  a_String :> StringJoin["\"", a, "\""]]
```

FilePrint shows the data exactly how it looks in the CSV, including the double quotes.

```
FilePrint["text.csv"]
```

> ```
> 1, "2 ""two"" 2", 3
> 1, "2 ""two"" 2", 3
> ```

Import retrieves the data the same as the string in the Export statement.

```
Import["text.csv"]
```

> ```
> {{1, "2 \"\"two\"\" 2", 3}, {1, "2 \"\"two\"\" 2", 3}}
> ```

**Interesting note**

It isn't straightforward to import numbers as strings in single quotes since they get converted to numbers.  For example.

```
Export["text.csv",
 {{1, "2.2", 3}, {1, "\"2.2\"", 3}, {1, "two", 3}, {1, "\"two\"", 3}} /.
  a_String :> StringJoin["\"", a, "\""]]

FilePrint["text.csv"]
```

> ```
> 1, "2.2", 3
> 1, ""2.2"", 3
> 1, "two", 3
> 1, ""two"", 3
> ```

```
Import["text.csv"]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2.2`, 3}, {1, "\"2.2\"", 3}, {1, "two", 3}, {1, "\"two\"", 3}}
> ```

This workaround retrieves one string 22 in single quotes.

```
Import["text.csv"] /. a_String :> If[NumberQ@
    ToExpression[StringTrim[a, "\""]], StringTrim[a, "\""], a]
```

> ```
>   {{1, 2.2`, 3}, {1, "2.2", 3}, {1, "two", 3}, {1, "\"two\"", 3}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. what about proper escaping for quote marks inside the string? The docs for csv I linked to require "" as the escape for each inner double quote mark.

Comment: I feel this is something that should be done with Export options, no manual replacement rules, no?

Comment: Quote marks inside the string should already be escaped otherwise Mathematica would see them a separate strings, e.g. `"two"2"two"` is two strings and a number multiplied together.  With escapes in the strings your example can be: `Export["~/text.csv", {{1, "2\"two\"2", 3}, {1, "2\"two\"2", 3}} /. 
  a_String :> StringJoin["\"", a, "\""]]`

Comment: Re: "*isn't this something that should be done with Export?*" I think the answer is summed up by this post: [**Writing numbers as strings in a .csv file**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b952d2c-42b5-437c-a6be-c5943a184acd/writing-numbers-as-strings-in-a-csv-file?forum=netfxbcl) - quote: "Here's the thing, with CSV you are COMPLETELY limited in what you can do with the text. ..."

Comment: Obviously you can put as many double quotes as you like in the CSV to conform with the specs, e.g. `Export["~/text.csv", {{1, "2\"\"two\"\"2", 3}, {1, "2\"\"two\"\"2", 3}} /. a_String :> StringJoin["\"", a, "\""]]`.  The CSV written out contains no backslashes, as shown by FilePrint.  (They are put back in if the CSV is imported into Mathematica using Import.)